# Why is the ORDER BY clause in a view ignored as soon as it's called with a WHERE claue?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, view, order-by

I have a view that joins several tables, just to simplify a frequently called query. This view has an ORDER BY clause on a calculated field (the order will never be different). (on SQL Server Express 2008 R2).

The basic idea is like this (simplified):

```
SELECT [EventType].Name, 
    [EventType].TotalOccurrences, 
    [Session].ID, 
    [Session].TotalOccurrences, 
    [Session].TotalOccurrences / [EventType].TotalOccurrences AS saturation
FROM [EventType]
    INNER JOIN [Session] ON [EventType].ID = [Session].Event
ORDER BY saturation
```

This view will never be called without a where clause though (which in my case would almost return the entire database). It will always be with `WHERE [EventType].ID = x`. However as soon as I add the where clause, the ORDER BY clause is ignored! Without the where clause it is working as expected.

Actually a different question but I'm throwing it in here while I'm at it, is there a better way to retrieve such info? The `[EventType].Name` and `[EventType].TotalOccurrences` will be identical for all returned rows, which is a small waist of network bandwidth. Not that that is a problem, but I'm wondering if anything exists to tackle that without the latency overhead of multiple round-trips to the database?

[Edit] The above sample was over-simplified, the calculated field has other factors so that it would return a different order than simply `ORDER BY [Session].TotalOccurrences` as it would in this example, but the principle should be clear.

[Edit2] From the answer I come to the conclusion that the Graphical Designer has more features than the underlying database:

[image: Bugus features in SSMS]

Comment: Remove the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` from your view. [They don't belong there](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior). Put the `ORDER BY` on the query that references the view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query you posted is not valid for creating a view; running `CREATE VIEW xy AS` for this query will result in an error. Are you using a `TOP` clause?

A view, being a table expression (a set), can't have the order defined, since that would be against the principles of a relational model (there is no order for rows in a relational table - a set is an unordered collection of tuples). Same goes for other table expressions - derived tables, CTEs etc.

From [BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) about the `ORDER BY` clause:

> The ORDER BY clause is **not valid** in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, and subqueries, unless either the TOP or OFFSET and FETCH
>   clauses are also specified. When ORDER BY is used in these objects,
>   the clause is **used only to determine the rows returned** by the TOP
>   clause or OFFSET and FETCH clauses. The ORDER BY clause **does not**
>   **guarantee ordered results** when these constructs are queried, unless
>   ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

Long story short: **Use the `ORDER BY` clause in the outer query that references the view.** Do not use it in a view. Even using it with `TOP(100) PERCENT` (or on SQL Server 2012, the `OFFSET-FETCH` equivalent) does not guarantee presentation order, it just means you'll get the top 100% of the rows, in any order.

Comment: +1 Also relevant [TOP 100 Percent ORDER BY Considered Harmful.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx)

Comment: =+1 Also see [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

Comment: Actually I used the Designer in Management Studio, which indeed added `TOP (100) PERCENT` to the start. Strange that they added the `Sort Type` and `Sort Order` columns to the designer while they actually should not be used... By the way, if I add '= @input' to the filter column I get a warning and cannot save the view (@input needs to be defined). I can test it though (also seems crazy to me). Probably I'd rather make this a stored procedure If I want any performance benefit (cached execution plan)? I'm kind of losing the practical use for a view now, is there any?

Comment: The `TOP (100) PERCENT` being suggested by the view designer was actually [reported as a bug on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/249248/management-studio-generates-invalid-top-100-percent-order-by-in-views), it's even marked as fixed... well, seems it's **not** fixed. Concerning the usage of an input parameter - can't do that in a view. Closest thing to a "parameterized view" is an [**inline** table-valued function (ITVF)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) - it's still a table expressions, but it can use input parameters.

Comment: About view usage, see [Scenarios for Using Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188250(v=sql.105).aspx). There are also a couple of SO questions already about that subject.